# Can I freeze undercooked (pink) chicken to finish cooking later on?

Tags: freezing

Cooked chicken breasts, thermometer was not working properly, so I thought they were done. Took out, let sit few minutes, cut open to discover most of the meat was slightly pink. I cut it up and froze it in small batches to use in the the next week or two. I had second thoughts about freezing in the first place but could not find any answers. Can you help?

Comment: What kind of cooking technique did you use?

Comment: Personally I'd be concerned that the meat in the center has now been raised to optimum bacteria growth temperature and never took past it to the kill zone. Not sure on your cooking or cooling technique, how long in total do you think this chicken will have been above 3c?

Comment: This strikes me as a dangerous practice. You might get away with it, but chicken poisoning can be quite unpleasant. People, those who live, will hate you for it; if it happens.

Comment: I baked 2 large chicken breasts in oven on 350 degrees for 45 minutes. Digital thermometer read 178 so I took them out of oven thinking they were overcooked. Ten minutes before, the thermometer read 124! Because I was on the phone, I let them sit for 20 min to finish conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely fine! The only thing I would worry about is when you are re-cooking them. Let them come down to room temperature before you throw them on the heat, otherwise, you'll get overcooked/burnt edges and a barely cooked centre. I would just be wary about keeping them in the freezer for over two weeks, not for health and safety, but just for taste and culinary standards.

For when you take them out for your meal; enjoy!

Comment: I wouldn't bring them up to room temperature out of fear of bacterial growth. Putting them in the fridge to defrost seems a lot safer.

Comment: @nick Agreed. But the answerer probably meant not to throw in the frozen pieces.